# "invalid device symbol" for pointers that are struct fields

Tags: cuda

I have the code snippets shown below. The two calls to "cudaMemcpyToSymbol" are essentially identical (all the operations to dev_a, dev_b are also the same), but when I ran the code, it reported an "invalid device symbol" error only for the second call to "cudaMemcpyToSymbol". If I deleted it, then the code ran without any problem. Does anyone know what might be the reason? Thanks.

```
struct aStruct {
  double *a;
  double *b;
};

__device__ struct aStruct as;

int main(void) {

double *dev_a, *dev_b;
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(double) ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(double) ) );
...
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(as.a, &dev_a, sizeof(double *)) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(as.b, &dev_b, sizeof(double *)) );
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, `as.a` and `as.b` are not valid device symbols. `as` *is* a device symbol, but members of the structure itself don't have symbol table entries and you cannot directly apply a `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` on them.

To solve this, do something like the following:

```
struct aStruct _as;

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&_as.a, N * sizeof(double) ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&_as.b, N * sizeof(double) ) );

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(as, &_as, sizeof(struct aStruct)) );
```

[disclaimer written in browser, not compiled or tested, use at own risk]

ie. copy a completely initialised `struct aStruct` only the symbol, rather than trying to copy member by member.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a lot. Just have a follow-up question, what should I do if I later on want to pass say as.a to the kernel launch? Do I have to use "cudaMemcpyFromSymbol" the whole struct to host and pass the first field? What if "as" is also a field in another struct? Do I have to do this one by one? I read from previous posts that multiple level of indirection is not recommended, but I need it for my application. Is there easy way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: If `as` is declared as a `__device__` variable at compilation unit scope, you don't need to pass it as a kernel, it can be accessed directly from inside code. If you really need to pass a struct from the host to a kernel, pass the `_as` as shown in my example code by value. Also, if this answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it, which removes it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am new to stackoverflow and didn't know the "rules". I have accepted the answer. As to the follow-up question, I think I found a way to solve it now, thanks to your suggestion.